# Material UI AutoComplete React. Display different options in list and save different option in form state (with multiple values)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I intend to use Autocomplete such that it stores a certain property of an object in the form state and displays a different property in the autocomplete option list. For example, if the option list is as follows:

```
[
    { gender_name_short: "F", gender_name_long: "Female" },
    { gender_name_short: "M", gender_name_long: "Male" },
    { gender_name_short: "O", gender_name_long: "Other" }
]
```

I intend to store gender_name_short in the form state and display gender_name_long in the dropdown list. I was able to achieve this and here is the codesandbox link for the implementation I did (Can you also suggest a better way?)
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bogdan-6lyxs?file=/src/App.js:231-412

Now my issue is that I want to also be able to store multiple values in an array,not applicable in this example as when person cannot have multiple genders, but I would like to use it for other use cases. So how should I go about doing that

### Current Behavior

If I add the 'multiple' prop to the Autocomplete component i get the error
TypeError
Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

### Expected Behavior

stores the multiple values in an array in its respective short_name_format
eg) ['M','F','O']

### Steps to Reproduce

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bogdan-6lyxs?file=/src/App.js:231-412
Steps:

1. Currently the code works without multiple to give a demo of what works
2. Un-comment multiple in App.js in Autocomplete call (prop)
3. Change the initialisation of gender to an empty list

Comment: Well documented question - well done! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-a-63160821-iguiu?file=/src/FormikAutoComplete.js:194-259) shows a possible solution to your problem.

Checkout the `transformValue` util I've added at the top of `FormikAutocomplete.js`:

```
const tranformValue = (value, fieldtosave) =>
  Array.isArray(value)
    ? value.map(v => v[fieldtosave] || v)
    : value[fieldtosave];
```

And its usage:

```
<Autocomplete
      onChange={(_, value) =>
        setFieldValue(name, value ? tranformValue(value, fieldtosave) : null)
      }
 ...
/>
```

Basically, what you were missing is that when the `Autocomplete` is set to `multiple` the `onChange` `value` is an array.